# Creating SCWDP for publishing service

Tags: deployment, publishing-service

We have Sitecore 10.1 in Azure PAAS scaled. We are planning to upgrade to Sitecore 10.3
Along with it, we will be upgrading the Publishing service also.

So we thought of upgrading the publishing service through scwdp package. As Sitecore provides a normal package, we thought of creating the scwdp package ourselves.

The problem is Sitecore says to have a local instance and then create the scwdp package (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sat/28/sitecore-azure-toolkit/packaging-a-sitecore-solution-for-the-microsoft-azure-app-service.html)

Or I am getting it wrong with the understanding '**from a ZIP file**'

How you have created it?